# Which is correct: vector<const string> OR const vector<string>?

Tags: c++, vector

Which is correct: `vector<const string>` OR `const vector<string>?`

I want to create an `std::vector` of `std::string`s, and I won't make changes to it.
But I am not sure which of the two ways is better and why.

Comment: Are the strings constant, or the vector?

Comment: @stark Hmm interesting question. Well, ok I see your point. I won't add new elements to the vector. I want to initialize it with few strings and then it will remain that way.

Comment: There's always `const vector<const string>`. Of course, you only need to go to all this trouble if you need the `vector` and `string` APIs; you could just use `const char* const []` if you didn't.

Comment: `std::vector<const std::string>` shouldn't even compile, which makes this question easy...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your only choices are those two and you want the program to compile, use `const std::vector<std::string>`.

If you don't mind compilation errors (both on [GCC4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d0967ce16f1e953) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df27c60ecf77c406)), probably due to the fact that `const std::string` does not meet the requirement of [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) (prior to C++11) or [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable) (since C++11), even though, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365331/which-is-correct-vectorconst-string-or-const-vectorstring/21365478?noredirect=1#comment32309820_21365478), it's mostly because it's not [`Destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Destructible), use `std::vector<const std::string>`.

Comment: The actual problem is that `const std::string` is not [`Destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Destructible), as witnessed by the compiler error messages complaining about the absence of a valid `operator delete`: "`no matching function for call to 'operator delete(const std::basic_string<char>*&)`". You can - in theory - declare a `std::vector<T>` for a `T` that isn't `CopyAssignable` or `MoveAssignable` as long as you don't try to put any elements in it. ([Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45391a6367953af1)).

Comment: what's the best to obtain mutable `vector` of const `string`s though?